# OpenLDAP won't start and won't log why

Tags: openldap, fedora

Recently needed to restart OpenLDAP on one of our servers. When I restart the service, the command prompt just sits there waiting for something. I never get the `[ OK ]`. If I `CTRL+C` out of it, it says

```
...killed.
/etc/openldap/cacerts/company.crt is not readable by "ldap[WARNING]
```

Just to prove a point, I made `/etc/openldap` 777 recursively. I still get the error.

I don't see anything in `/var/log` changing to give me some feedback. Where do I need to look to fix this?

This is an old server running Fedora 8 (ya I know, blame the previous IT guy).

Comment: Is SELinux enabled?  This smells like SELinux.

Comment: SELinux status: disabled

Comment: did you check with a ps that your service isn't running? Might be a zombie there, and that's why you can't restart openldap service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some ideas for additional debugging.  These are only necessary if you're absolutely positive it's not a permission problem...

First, try running slapd in debug mode:

```
slapd -u ldap -g ldap -d 65
```

Note that the argument to -d is a bit field, values for which can be found in the `slapd.conf` man page (look for `loglevel`).  `65` is trace + config, which is usually sufficiently verbose for this sort of problem.  This may or may not show you anything useful.

If that doesn't work, we can use `strace` (a system call tracer) to figure out exactly what's going on.  Run `slapd` like this:

```
strace -o /tmp/trace -f -s 1024 slapd -u ldap -g ldap -d 7
```

When it dies, you'll have a file `/tmp/trace` containing all the system calls from `slapd`.  For the curious `-f` makes strace follow forks (not really necessary in this case, but it's my default), and `-s 1024` makes strace print up to 1024 bytes of string arguments in the trace log.

Now, use `grep` to look for references to `company.crt` in this file.  In theory you'll find something that looks like this if their is a permission problem:

```
open("/tmp/company.crt", O_RDONLY)      = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Or something like this if the file is missing:

```
open("/tmp/company.crt", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

A successful open looks like this:

```
open("/tmp/company.crt", O_RDONLY)      = 3
```

Where that `3` is the file descriptor returned by open (and will probably be some other positive integer).

Take a look and see if something obvious jumps out.  Let me know if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set /etc/openldap to 777.  Permissions are necessary to make things work correctly sometimes.  I would suggest changing it back to 755.

You might have the incorrect user and or permission on cacerts

drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr 19  2007 cacerts/